# How to enable internet access inside Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

If I run `curl google.com`, I can't see the output, only a blank page. My Vagrantfile contains:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "trumobi"
 #config.vm.box_url = "http://192.168.136.129/package.box"
  config.ssh.default.username = "trumobi"
  config.vm.network :public_network
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8000, guest: 8000
end
```

Answer (score 66):

If you are using **Vagrant + VirtualBox + Ubuntu**, you might want to add the following block to your VagrantFile:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
end
```

If you are using ubuntu, and you think your firewall is `on`, here's how you turn off the firewall:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Comment: after adding the above comments in my vagrantfile, im facing the same prob. When i give curl www.google.com, i cant able to view the ouput. Only blank screen is been displayed. Please find below the updated vagrantfile.

Comment: `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|`

  `config.vm.box = "trumobi"`
 `#config.vm.box_url = "http://192.168.136.129/package.box"`
  `config.ssh.default.username = "trumobi"`
  `config.vm.network :public_network`
  `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8000, guest: 8000`
`config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|`
    `v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]`
    `v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]`
`end`
`end`

Comment: after a long time it throws an error:curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Comment: You might want to check the firewall setting of your vagrant box.

Comment: could you please help me how to check it. Im new to this vagrant

Comment: Im using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Checkout this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/250775/how-do-i-turn-off-the-firewall-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: i checked in my terminal , ufw status is disabled only. Now also facing same problem

Comment: I think user2439278 didn't run `vagrant reload` after adding the suggested configuration to the Vagrantfile: it solved the problem for me.

Comment: works fine after launch `vagrant reload --provision`

Comment: it works in the machine where vagrant is running. But when i tried in another system, its not working. Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Thank you! This fixed all my issues under Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Perfect for me as well on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 34):

This happens sometimes for me if I switch the host network connection, like disconnecting my laptop Ethernet cable and start using the wireless network.
I found that rebooting the Vagrant vm (vagrant halt, vagrant up) fixes things.

Comment: that's exactly what I try first and most often fixes it - like: have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Apparently this can also happen on a Windows (Server Core 2016) VM when my laptop sleeps and wakes up again. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

Disabling firewall helped me.
In my CentOS guest box I did:

```
# sudo service iptables save
# sudo service iptables stop
# sudo chkconfig iptables off
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried all of the above without success (Vagrant+Virtualbox+Ubuntu 14.04). Virtualbox was showing 'Adapter 1 (NAT): cable disconnected'. Adding the following to my Vagrantfile fixed it:

```
config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|
  vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cableconnected1', 'on']
end
```

Found here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7648